# Mysql Grouping and fetching row corresponding to a maximum field value within that group

Tags: mysql

I'm confused about how to fit together group and max in mysql. Here's my problem:

I need to group data and then based on a maximum value among that group, I need to fetch that row. Here's a sample:

**Table**

```
ID Player Score

1    1     5

2    1     7

3    2     5

4    2     8

5    2     9
```

After grouping on based of players and fetching all the fields corresponding to maximum score for each player

**Result**

```
ID Player Score

2    1     7

5    2     9
```

Please help me writing the query for this problem.

Comment: If there is same highest score for same player then which player you want to select?

Comment: @ManishJain did that worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to achieve what you want but there could be some easier way:

```
SELECT s.id, 
       s.player, 
       s.score
  FROM scores s
  JOIN (SELECT id, 
               player, 
               MAX(score) AS total
         FROM scores
     GROUP BY player
       ) r
    ON r.total = s.score AND 
       r.player = s.player;
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ea702/2)

Basically you're comparing the score and the player to get the correct ones as listed in your example.

However if you have multiple entries of the same player with same score you might have a problem there, if you want the first or last it might work with ordering but aside from that it would not work.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The only thing is for the multiple entries with the same score, how can I choose the entry with highest id?

Comment: You mean after the complete query? The results would still be having the entries with the lower ids, right? My requirement is to have only the score with the highest id. Could you please update your fiddle with your suggestion?